# hyperlink tag in <p> tag

Tags: html, hyperlink

So i'm trying to assign a hyperlink to a single word in a {p} tag in an .aspx page in MS expressions.

My problem:
when i try to do this:

```
    <p>Some text with a <a href="******">HYPERLINK</a> then there's more text here like this</p>
```

it shows up in the browser as such:

some text with a

HYPERLINK

then there's more text here like this

I'm trying to get it all on one line like it should be.. any ideas??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My best guess, is that your anchor tag is styled as display : block, can you confirm this by using inspect element, or providing a link to where this bug is occurring?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Nobr](http://davidwalsh.name/nobr-css) html tag. Anything in between  will not be broken in multiple lines.

```
<a href="#"><nobr>My long sentence</nobr></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<nobr>` tag is deprecated.

One can use : white-space : nowrap ;

```
<a style = " white-space:nowrap; " href="******">HYPERLINK</a>
```